# Cannot find Resharper setting that shows parameter or method type

Tags: visual-studio-2019, resharper

I am using Resharper in Visual Studio 2019.

I want to drop these extra tags that are showing up in my code:

[image]

I cannot find the setting that disables this and I've looked everywhere. I had to reset my interface due to changing to many things trying to find this setting.

Anyone know where I find the option to disable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These *extra tags* are the so-called *inlay hints* ([JetBrains docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Inline_Parameter_Name_Hints.html)).

You can enable or disable them under *ReSharper | Options | Environment | Inlay Hints | General*:
[image]